# Does sitecore support non-password protected RSS feed out of the box?

Tags: rss

I've used sitecore's built in [RSS feed abilities](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/setting-up-rss-feeds.html) and it appears to be only accessible via logging into sitecore. Is there a way to enable this to work without being logged into sitecore?

Comment: The documentation you linked shows how to setup the RSS feed for public consumption. Once you follow those steps, users can use your public RSS feed url as long as your website allows for anonymous access.

Comment: my site allows anon access, still doesnt allow me to access it unless i authenticate. It keeps trying to redirect me to `/login`

Comment: Is this for all users? Did you try in a different browser/incognito window/clearing your cookies? Make sure the anonymous user also has read access to your RSS item in the content tree using the `Access Viewer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/582960

Essentially, add the following to the web.config file:

```
<location path="sitecore/shell/feeds">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore/shell/applications/feeds">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This fixed the issue for me (on sitecore 9.0.2)

Comment: It's what we eneded up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore, there are two types of RSS feeds:

- **RSS feeds** – feeds that website visitors can subscribe to.
- **Client RSS feeds** – feeds in the Content Editor that Sitecore users can subscribe to.

In Sitecore, most RSS readers do not support authentication, which means that users who subscribe to a Sitecore Client RSS feeds have direct access to the item that is specified in the URL of the RSS feed – they do not have to identify themselves to the Sitecore security system. However, the Sitecore security system verifies that they are authorized users if they try to perform any actions associated with the feed.

In your case, it will work fine without authentication after creating the RSS, just make sure to clear your browser cache or open in a different browser if it is redirecting you to the login page.

> **Important** : Sitecore users should not share RSS feeds.

Comment: `However, the Sitecore security system verifies that they are authorized users if they try to perform any actions associated with the feed.` It still requires authentication, EVEN if all we're doing is reading and it's allowed annon access.